# Error bitwise error img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, imgInv, mask=None)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv

*This is my eror*

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\VirtualPainter\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/VirtualPainter/main.py
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\VirtualPainter\main.py", line 74, in <module>
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, imgInv, mask=None)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:234: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*This is my code*

```
imgCanvas = np.zeros((720, 1280, 3), np.uint8)

    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgCanvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, imgInv = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    imgInv = cv2.cvtColor(imgInv, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    #########################################
    #PROBLEM#
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, imgInv, mask=None)
    img = cv2.bitwise_or(img, imgCanvas, mask=None)
    #########################################

    cv2.imshow("Camera", img)
    #cv2.imshow("Canvas", imgCanvas)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

i already tried to put the values but on bitwise, what i got is just an eror, i want to mask the canvas and the camera, so the line i draw can be show on the camera not on the canvas

Comment: both arguments have to have the same number of channels. yours don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the 'imgInv' image has 2 channels although it must have same number of channels ....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).